# Bash-Skript (Cronjob): Programm öffnen hat falsche Sprache

Tags: ubuntu, bash, cron, env

Which ENV must be exported that a bash cronjob script opens the program in the correct language?

If I open the bash script so manually in the command-line the program is opened in the correct language.

However, if the program is opened via the cronjob, the program runs via the wrong language?

The LANG ENV can not be I checked that is also in the Crontab on the same language.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** You need to set `LC_ALL` or `LC_MESSAGES`. For example:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
```

The list of all supported locales from your machine can be obtained with: `locale -a` and `locale -av` for more details.

**Details**

From `crontab(5)` man page (`man -S5 crontab`):

> An active line in a crontab is either an environment setting or a cron command.  An environment setting is of the form:

```
name = value
```

> By  default, cron sends a mail using the `Content-Type:` header of
> `text/plain` with the `charset=` parameter set to the
> `charmap/codeset` of the locale in which crond(8) is started up, i.e.,
> either the default system locale, if no `LC_*` environment variables are
> set, or the locale specified by the `LC_*` environment variables (see
> `locale(7)`).  Different character encodings can be used for mailing
> cron job outputs by setting the `CONTENT_TYPE` and
> `CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING` variables in a crontab to the correct
> values of the mail headers of those names.

From `locale(7)` man page (`man -S7 locale`):

> `LC_MESSAGES`
> This  category  affects  the language in which messages
> are displayed and what an affirmative or negative answer looks like.
> The GNU C library contains the `gettext(3)`, `ngettext(3)`, and `rpmatch(3)`
> functions to ease the use of this information.  The GNU gettext family
> of functions also obey the environment variable `LANGUAGE` (containing a
> colon-separated list of locales) if the category is set to a valid
> locale other  than  `C`.   This category also affects the behavior of
> `catopen(3)`.

> `LC_ALL`
> All of the above.

To troubleshoot the environment of a process, you can display it with the following command. Replace `<PID>` with the process id of your cron job that is still running. You will need to test with a cronjob that takes a few minutes at least (e.g. `sleep 300`).

```
ps e -wwp <PID>
```